# Get value of first row first column in Azure Synapse DataFlow

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a string date value that I want to set as Effective Start Date to a column in Azure Dataflow.

That value is in column Market_Participant_Name row 1 (it acts like the header of the file).

I have the following in my Dataflow Expression Builder
`toDate(Market_Participant_Name, 'dd MMMM yyyy')`

This works but only for the same row and the rest of the column is null. This is beacause it dynamically checks the value of the column with different rows.

I want to set the value of the first row to the entire column. How do I go about doing this inside the Dataflow if possible?

I have tried `toDate(first(Market_Participant_Name), 'dd MMMM yyyy')`but this only works for Data Factory. I'm currently trying to discover if there is a way to set that value to a variable but I can't seem to figure out how to do that in Synapse.

Answer (score 0):

`first()` function available in synapse dataflows. But it is an aggregate function. So, you need to use **Window** transformation to achieve your requirement.

This is my sample source data:

```
id,name,Age,DOB
1,Rakesh,22,2000-02-16
2,Laddu,23,1999-10-16
3,MS,42,1999-07-27
```

First use a surrogate key transformation and give a new column name with incremental value as 1.

**This will give the result like this:**

[image]

Then use window transformation. Give the window settings like this.

[image]

In **Window columns**, use `first()` function.

[image]

Keep the default settings in the `Over` and `Range by`.

This will give the desired result:

[image]

Remove the `mykey` column using select transformation after this and use this `new` column as per your requirement.